# Deploy ASP.NET app in a subdirectory

Tags: asp.net

I've a small and cheap hosting which I use for my "company". The main site (at root level) uses WordPress.

I would like to deploy some application in subdirectory, for example

> www.mysite.com/demo_app1
>   www.mysite.com/demo_app2

Is it possible **without accessing to IIS virtual directory ** ?

At the moment I get "Parse Error: unable to load 'myapp._Default' "

I can't access to IIS because my hosting is cheap (maybe .. too cheap ;) ) ...

Comment: Do they even support asp.net on your package? The easiest thing to do is to ring and ask them, even if they are cheap they should have some customer support or at least an FAQ on their site.

Comment: You don't need virtual directories for this, but probably not - you really need to create a new IIS application in the management UI at the root of each app on disk.

Comment: Yes, my hosting allow Asp.NET ... Other app was deployed with success on the same hosting company! Now, when i try to use subdirectory for different application, i'm getting error !!!

Comment: I used to get that error when we would deploy a .net 2 app using a 1.1 app pool.  May want to make sure that you have the correct app pool type (1.1, 2, or 4) (3.0 and 3.5 just use 2.0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Its impossible to create new web application from web.config on sub directories of your site.**

The reasons are basic because you need to have higher access level, and also connect your web application to a specific pool. This can not been done from web.config it self.

Now one other solution to your problem is to try to make them run all together if your seconds applications are small. To do that use the root bin directory to add your dlls, and use the root web.config for add the extra settings for your sub applications. This can work if you do not have so difficult applications on your sub directories that not conflict with the root.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least your root directory marked as an ASP.NET application.

Anyway, edit your web.config and set your compilation mode to debug and check that custom errors are disabled. That's going to allow you to see what's going on.